# How to run batch processing in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, batch-processing

I have an Excel file with several tabs. How can I run my shiny App looping through the tabs -- using one tab (one at a time) as input?

Here is a simple example. In reality, `raw_input` is the Excel file with 3 tabs.
In this code, out3() will only be run for tab1.

Final outcome I am looking for is Output.csv with 3 tabs:

1. Tab1 is out3() calculated using tab1
2. Tab2 is out3() calculated using tab2
3. Tab3 is out3() calculated using tab3

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::downloadButton('download_button', "Save")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
raw_input <- reactive({
  df <- data.frame(tab1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                   tab2 = c(4, 5, 6), 
                   tab3 = c(1, 1, 1)
})

# IN THIS EXAMPLE BELOW, IT ONLY RUNS FOR THE 1ST TAB
# I NEED TO RUN IT FOR EACH TAB

out1 <- reactive({
  return(raw_input()[[1]]**2)
})

out2 <- reactive({
  return(out1() * 5)
})

out3 <- reactive({
  return(out1()+out2())
})

output$download_button <- shiny::downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {paste("Output.csv")},
  content  = function(file) {
    write.csv(out3(), file)
  }
)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do operation on the whole df for all columns together, no need to do it column by column, like this

```r
(df <- data.frame(tab1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
           tab2 = c(4, 5, 6), 
           tab3 = c(1, 1, 1)))
#>   tab1 tab2 tab3
#> 1    1    4    1
#> 2    2    5    1
#> 3    3    6    1
(out1 <- df^2)
#>   tab1 tab2 tab3
#> 1    1   16    1
#> 2    4   25    1
#> 3    9   36    1
(out2 <- out1 * 5)
#>   tab1 tab2 tab3
#> 1    5   80    5
#> 2   20  125    5
#> 3   45  180    5
(out3 <- out1 + out2)
#>   tab1 tab2 tab3
#> 1    6   96    6
#> 2   24  150    6
#> 3   54  216    6
```